# How to include random images?

Tags: graphics, random-numbers

I'd like to make LaTeX pick one image file randomly from a series of eight images, and include it. I found that ''lcg'' package can generate random numbers:

```
\usepackage{lcg}
\reinitrand[counter=sec,first=1,last=8]
```

So i expected this line to include one of the images randomly:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{excl0\rand\arabic{sec}c.png}
```

Where the file names are excl01c.png, excl02c.png, and so on.
The result was not like i have imagined, i got an error message:

```
Runaway definition?
->excl0\cr@nd = 126\advance \cr@nd \inputlineno \multiply \cr@nd 3\advance \ETC
.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
<argument> Random number generator initiali
                                       zed to \the \cr@nd
```

My question is what is the reason of this kind of error, and how to fix it, how to make LaTeX choose an image file randomly?

Comment: Put `\rand` before `\includegraphics`

Comment: wow egreg, you solved it easily. thank you! could you put it in an answer, then i can accept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `\rand` instruction computes a random number and stores it in the `sec` counter. On the other hand, the argument to `\includegraphics` should be a file name (after macro expansion), not the set of instructions to compute it.

Just perform the computation before doing `\includegraphics`:

```
\rand\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{excl0\arabic{sec}c.png}
```

### Note

`\rand` will do some computations which are not allowed in an "expansion only" context. The string passed as argument to `\includegraphics` (or `\input`, that uses the same mechanism) *can* contain macros, but these should be able to expand to *characters only*.

### Extensions

If you need to use files numbered from 01 to 20, say, you have to ensure that the command prints a padding zero for numbers less than 10; the LaTeX kernel provides `\two@digits` for this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printrandom}{\two@digits{\thesec}}
\makeatother

\rand\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{excl\printrandom c.png}
```

For more digits, you can emulate the behavior of `\two@digits`:

1. Two digits

   ```
   \newcommand{\printrandom}{\ifnum\value{sec}<10 0\fi\arabic{sec}}
   ```
2. Three digits

   ```
   \newcommand{\printrandom}{\ifnum\value{sec}<100 0\fi\ifnum\value{sec}<10 0\fi\arabic{sec}}
   ```

Use again `\rand\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{excl\printrandom c.png}`

Answer (score 5):

Use `\rand` before of `\includegraphics` and the `\thesec` in the file name do de job. In the MWE the `images1.png` to `image4.png` are their respective handwritten numbers:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lcg}
    \reinitrand[counter=sec,first=1,last=4]
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}

    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}
    \rand\includegraphics[width=3em]{image\thesec}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: I really answered too late for making the MWE, but perhaps a MWE is easiest that the **perfect** explanation of @egreg :)

Comment: This is exactly what @egreg already said both [in his comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72750/how-to-include-random-images#comment154483_72750) and [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72754/5049)...

Comment: @cgneider, I recognise that egreg has been the fastest (and best) responder on this side of the Pecos (see my first comment). But I keep because the value of the MWE (I hope this is not regarded as a lack of etiquette).

Comment: I simply wondered why you repeated an already given answer. But since it's been upvoted I guess it has been proven useful :)

Comment: @cgneider, simply I saw his answer after sending my answer. These things happen when you are not an expert and takes time find the solution, make the MWE and check if it works. :(

Comment: I know... :) But IIRC you should have been warned that another answer had been posted? BTW my name's with “ie” instead of “ei” ;)

Comment: Surely. Faults of multitasking ... Sorry also for the misspelling, @cgnieder