# Random numbers and further usage

Tags: tables, random-numbers

I am designing random excercise sheets for my students. I'm able to get random numbers without repetition using the code from [Random number without repetition in an \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145028/random-number-without-repetition-in-an-includegraphics). Now I want to use the random numbers to create unique tables. Eg. I have 20 possible mc questions and I want to use 5 different questions for each student. Each question is outsourced in a .tex file.

Example:

- random number 1 -> \input{1.tex}
- random number 3 -> \input{3.tex}
- random number 8 -> \input{8.tex}

Each X.tex file contains a table row like

`a & b & c & d \\`

Now my problem is the following error code if I use the tabular environment. I don't understand where the missing } is.

`! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <template> \unskip \hfil } \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate  l.56 \randomincludegraphics{total}?`

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\declarenumlist#1#2#3{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1@listcount}{\newcounter{#1@listcount}}{}%
  \setcounter{#1@listcount}{1}%
  \begingroup
  \count@=#2\relax
  \def\x{}%
  \loop
  \edef\x{\x{\the\count@}}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname#1@\number\count@ @used\endcsname\relax
  \ifnum\count@<#3\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \stepcounter{#1@listcount}%
  \repeat
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{#1}{\x}%
  }\x
  \expandafter\mathchardef\csname #1@number\endcsname\value{#1@listcount}%
  \setcounter{#1@listcount}{0}%
}

\newcommand{\pgfmathuniquerandomitem}[2]{%
  \pgfmathrandomitem#1{#2}%
  \ifnum\value{#2@listcount}=\@nameuse{#2@number}%
    \@latex@warning{List #2 exhausted}%
  \else
    \@ifundefined{#2@#1@used}%
      {\stepcounter{#2@listcount}\global\@namedef{#2@#1@used}{used}}%
      {\pgfmathuniquerandomitem#1{#2}}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\randomincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfmathuniquerandomitem\z{#2}%
% Uncomment the following line for the production version
  \input{\z.tex}
% and remove the following line
%  I want to include \texttt{\z.pdf} with options ``\texttt{#1}''
  \endgroup
}



%I want 2 numbers because I have 2 possible rows 

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\declarenumlist{total}{1}{2}

\randomincludegraphics{total}

\randomincludegraphics{total}

\end{tabular}



%content of 1.tex
% a & b & c & d \\

% content of 2.tex
% e & f & g & h \\


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, well, nine years ago was a very different situation! Let me try and fix a “modern” solution.

Comment: The `xsim` package also offers this feature, see section 10. _Printing Random Exercises from A Collection_ in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/xsim-manual.pdf) on page 26.

Comment: Another option is `esami`, see section 7.2 _Commands to choose from a list_ in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/esami/doc/esami-doc-en.pdf).

Comment: There is also `exercisebank`, but that doesn't offer randomized selection so you would need to write some code yourself to get a list of 5 random distinct numbers to use in the `\makeset` macro of that package (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercisebank/exercisebank-doc.pdf) on page 6).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order